# Set element attribute using Jquery attr() fails in for-loop during ASP.NET Postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am attempting to change the src of an image using jQuery on a .NET ASPX page during postback.

The code works perfect on page load as long as it is outside of `prm.add_endRequest(function () {});`. However, once a postback occurs and `prm.add_endRequest(function () {});` runs it gives attr undefined.

Here is a simplified code sample:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        var defaultImage = '<%=DefaultImage %>';

        function initializeStars() {
            var star1 = $('#star1<%=uuid %>');
            var star2 = $('#star2<%=uuid %>');
            var star3 = $('#star3<%=uuid %>');
            var star4 = $('#star4<%=uuid %>');
            var star5 = $('#star5<%=uuid %>');

            var stars = new Array(star1, star2, star3, star4, star5);

            console.log('stars', stars);

            for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                console.log('stars[', i, '] before', stars[i]); 
                console.log('stars[', i, '] attr src before', stars[i].attr('src'));
                console.log('defaultImage', defaultImage);

                stars[i].attr('src', defaultImage);  // Assign defaults.
                stars[i].css('font-size', '0px');

                console.log('stars[', i, '] after', stars[i]); 
                console.log('stars[', i, '] attr src', stars[i].attr('src'));
            }
        }

        initializeStars();
    });
```

Console Output:
[image]

You can see in the console output the following:

> stars[ 4 ] attr src before
>
> stars[ 4 ] attr src after https://d1ululg65bfe3q.cloudfront.net/images/icon/rating-stars-gray-36x54.png
>
> stars[ 0 ] attr src before undefined
>
> stars[ 0 ] attr src after undefined

The objective is to dynamically assign a `src` attribute to an `<img>` element.

**Update**

The following super simple code also yeilds `undefined`. There is no for-loop and no array.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    var defaultImage = '<%=DefaultImage %>';
    var star1 = $('#star1<%=uuid %>');

    console.log('PRM CASE'); 
    console.log('star1', star1);               

    console.log('star1 before', star1); 
    console.log('star1 attr src before', star1.attr('src'));
    console.log('defaultImage', defaultImage);

    star1.attr('src', defaultImage);  // Assign defaults.

    console.log('star1 after', star1); 
    console.log('star1 attr src after', star1.attr('src'));
}
```

Expanded Console Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this might work for you. Can you please try this approach ?

`console.log('stars[', i, '] attr src before', $(stars[i]).attr('src'));`

And can you expand this ?

[This console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgL3e.png)

Comment: This results in `undefined` because it is basically this `$($('#star1-uuid'))`.

Comment: Expanded console output added.